App Scripts условное форматирование начинает работать только если в ручную поменять любой символ на тот же самый
Подскажите, пожалуйста, с чем может быть связана данная проблема?
Есть функция, которая необходима, чтобы найти все дубликаты. Итогом получается необходимая формула, но она не работает, пока я её не отредактирую как-либо (сотру цифру 1 и напишу снова, например).
Решение похожей проблемы так и не нашёл
 var ruleGray = SpreadsheetApp.newConditionalFormatRule()
  .whenFormulaSatisfied('=И(НЕ(ЕПУСТО(' + firstCell + ')); СЧЁТЕСЛИ($' + columnLetter + '$3:$' + columnLetter + '; ' + firstCell + ') = 1)')
  .setBackground('#D3D3D3')  // Серый цвет
  .setRanges([sheet.getRange(range)])
  .build();


var ruleGreen = SpreadsheetApp.newConditionalFormatRule()
  .whenFormulaSatisfied('=И(НЕ(ЕПУСТО(' + firstCell + ')); СЧЁТЕСЛИ($' + columnLetter + '$3:$' + columnLetter + '$1000; ' + firstCell + ') = 2)')
  .setBackground('#00FF00')  // Зелёный цвет
  .setRanges([sheet.getRange(range)])
  .build();

var ruleRed = SpreadsheetApp.newConditionalFormatRule()
  .whenFormulaSatisfied('=И(НЕ(ЕПУСТО(' + firstCell + ')); СЧЁТЕСЛИ($' + columnLetter + '$3:$' + columnLetter + '$1000; ' + firstCell + ') > 2)')
  .setBackground('#FF0000')  // Красный цвет
  .setRanges([sheet.getRange(range)])
  .build();


Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Попробуйте вместо русских функций "И", "НЕ", "ЕПУСТО", "СЧЕТЕСЛИ" поставить их английские аналоги - "AND", "NOT" итд
